# Z3 finds model inconsistent with the axioms

Tags: python, function, z3, z3py, forall

When running this code on Python 3.6.7 with the z3-solver module (4.8.0.0), the model returned by z3 seems not valid with the axioms.

```
f = z3.Function('f', z3.IntSort(), z3.IntSort(), z3.IntSort())
x = z3.Int('x')
s = z3.Solver()
s.add(f(1, 10) == 42)
s.add(z3.ForAll([x], f(2, x) == f(1, x)))
s.check()
m = s.model()
print(m.eval(f(1, 10)))  # print 0
print(m.eval(f(2, 10)))  # print 0
```

Why didn't we get 42 as we can expect ?  Is there a problem with the axioms or the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your installation might be busted, as I cannot replicate this:

```
$ cat a.py
import z3
f = z3.Function('f', z3.IntSort(), z3.IntSort(), z3.IntSort())
x = z3.Int('x')
s = z3.Solver()
s.add(f(1, 10) == 42)
s.add(z3.ForAll([x], f(2, x) == f(1, x)))
print s.sexpr()
s.check()
m = s.model()
print(m.eval(f(1, 10)))  # print 0
print(m.eval(f(2, 10)))  # print 0

$ python a.py
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)
(assert (= (f 1 10) 42))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (f 2 x) (f 1 x))))

42
42
```

Note that I added `print s.sexpr()` to your code and it nicely printed the generated SMTLib. Do you see the same?

Comment: Thanks, I just realized it works fine with the latest version from Github (4.8.4) but not with the one provided by pip (4.8.0).